# problemas para instalar el npm para usar Vue.js en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Intento instalar npm para usar vue.js en mi proyecto laravel pero me sale este error cuando ejecuto el comando `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.4.162:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alberto89\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-17T20_25_48_205Z-debug.log
```

Estoy usando la version de node: `v9.11.1` y la version de npm: `5.6.0`. estimados colegas que podrá suceder.

Comment: te esta indicando problemas de conectividad, te conectas directo a la red o tu lap se conecta por medio de un proxy?

Comment: Seguramente sea un problema de proxy. Hay un problema cerrado similar en el repositorio de [GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17064) de npm. En el se dan varias soluciones, entre ellas las de ejecutar los comandos `npm config rm proxy` y `npm config rm https-proxy`. Coméntanos si resuelve tu problema.

Comment: mi lap se conecta por un proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que tu ordenador se conecta a través de un proxy y parece ser la única manera de conectarte, deberás modificar la configuración de **npm**. Para ello debes ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

```
$ npm config set proxy http://<user>:<pass>@<server>:<port>
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<user>:<pass>@<server>:<port>
```

Donde:

- **user**. El usuario que estás utilizando para conectarte a través del proxy.
- **pass**. La contraseña de este usuario.
- **server**. La dirección del servidor proxy.
- **port**. El puerto que utiliza el servidor proxy.

Puede que el usuario o la contraseña no sean necesarios, dependiendo de la configuración del proxy, en ese caso serían los mismos comandos sin la parte `<user>:<pass>@`. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando un proxy para conectarte a Internet, tienes que configurar npm para que reconozca ese proxy.

Abre una consola y pon el comando siguiente:

```
npm set proxy http://dominio_proxy:puerto
```

Donde dominio_proxy puede ser 10.254.45.1 o proxy.serv.cu
puerto es el número de puerto por el cual esta corriendo el servidore del proxy